# data management in "Skate Warehouse" (HTML5/JS DevExtreme)

Tags: javascript, datasource, devextreme

I'm testing the Demo sample "Skate Warehouse" (HTML5/JS DevExtreme).
Where does the app get the data for Products.js ?
Can I instead read the information from a text file and display it in products?

Products.js:

```js
window.DXSK8 = window.DXSK8 || {};
window.DXSK8.Store = window.DXSK8.Store || {};
window.DXSK8.Store.db = window.DXSK8.Store.db || {};

(function () {
    var db = {},
        TypeIds = {
            deck: "74C9F584-429F-4F5B-8A9F-007D6176D6E4",
            truck: "2D7D4288-E1D1-4116-AEEE-056EF87C011E",
            wheels: "3182DE2E-417D-4B1F-9E6D-1CB073DC5A04"
        }

    db.loadProduct = function(id, success, fail) {
        return DXSK8.db.Products.load({
            select: [
                "ID",
                "Name",
                "Price",
                "Quantity",
                "ImageUrl",
                "Brand.Name"
            ],
            filter: ["ID", new DevExpress.data.Guid(id)]
        }).done(function (product) {
            product = mapProduct(product[0]);
            success.call(this, product);
        }).fail(fail);
    };

    db.loadProducts = function(type, success, fail) {
        DXSK8.db.Products.load({
            select: [
                "ID",
                "Name",
                "Price",
                "Quantity",
                "ImageUrl",
                "Brand.Name"
            ],
            filter: ["Type.ID", new DevExpress.data.Guid(TypeIds[type])]
        }).done(function (products) {
            products = $.map(products, mapProduct);
            DevExpress.data.query(products)
                .groupBy("brandName")
                .enumerate()
                .done(function (products) {
                    success.call(this, products);
                })

        }).fail(fail);
    };

    function mapProduct(product) {
        var result = {
            id: product.ID,
            image: product.ImageUrl,
            name: product.Name,
            price: parseFloat(product.Price),
            quantity: product.Quantity,
            brandName: product.Brand.Name
        }
        return result;
    }



    $.extend(DXSK8.Store.db, db);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the "DXSK8.Service" project in the "DXSK8" solution. And the app data is stored here: `App_Data/SampleData.xml`

To get the data from browser, app uses the "DXSK8.Shared" project, file `data/db.js`. There is the [ODataContext](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/ApiReference/Data_Layer/ODataContext/) object that communicates with "DXSK8.Service" OData service. The configuration settings are here `DXSK8.Shared/shared.config.js`